# DIY - Vent Duct Cleaning of small condo with no ductwork - Power of Shop-Vac, tools, tips needed?

Tags: cleaning, ducts, vacuum

I own a small condo, 870 sq ft, built in the 70's that does not have any metal ductwork or any ductwork at all. (I looked in the air conditioning vents & all I see are the studs and drywall.)

Quote for professional is kind of high, $700 roughly, for only having 20 sq ft of cleaning to do which I figured I could do myself.  It only has 3 air conditioning vents where I would have to clean from.

I am wondering how big of a shop vac (cfm and hp) that I would need to suck up the dust where I don't have to clean it again for another 5 years.  I plan on buying a shop vac anyways and figured that I can buy a better one than the the bottom line.

Any other tools & tips would help to get the job done thoroughly?

Note - Just only A/C ducts, old condo has heat coming from baseboards.  This has not been address before on this site.

Comment: I don't know if you can ever get all or even most of the dust off of studs and drywall with a vac. With only 20 sq ft of area I would clean it as best I can and then install a HEPA filter on the air supply for future dust containment.

Comment: The professional quote goes mainly for the big expensive machine.  If you can get hoses and brushes into the vents, almost any vacuum should work.  The problem is getting enough hose into the vents and working them around the walls of the vents.